# How to make ng-view wait for XHR response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I´m trying to make the ng-view wait for a `xhr` request. I have two controllers for a routed `ng-view`, the first one is loaded perfectly. But the other doesn't gets rendered well, because the `xhr` response happens after `partial.html` is downloaded. How do I avoid the `partial.html` request until that client get the `xhr` response?

You can see below the code for the route configuration:

```js
var configuration = [
  '$routeProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
    routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/hotelinfo.html',
      controller: 'HotelInfo'
    }).when('/service/dept/:id', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/department.html',
      controller: 'Department'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
];
```

Below you can see the controller configuration that gets the `xhr` response

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

var Department = [
  '$scope',
  '$routeParams',
  function (scope, routeParams) {
    http.get('/service/dept/' + routParams.id).success(function (data) {
      scope.data = data;
    });
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$http.get` from your controller, call it from a resolve function on `$routeProvider` and inject it into the controller. That will cause Angular to not load your view until the promise from `$http` is resolved.

Comment: Any example of how to do it? im new in angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using resolve in the routeProvider. It returns a promise. The view will not load until that promise is resolved. You can resolve that promise in your controller.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider for more info.

```
var configuration = [
  '$routeProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function(routeProvider, locationProvider) {
    routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/partials/hotelinfo.html',
      controller: 'HotelInfo'
    }).when('/service/dept/:id', {
      template: '/partials/department.html',
      controller: 'Department',
      resolve: {
            deferred: function($q) {
                return $q.defer();
            }
        }
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

    locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
];


var Department = [
  '$scope',
  '$routeParams',
  'deferred',
  function (scope, routeParams, deferred) {
    http.get('/service/dept/' + routParams.id).success(function (data) {
      scope.data = data;
      deferred.resolve();
    });
  }
];
```

Comment: this works? Note that parameter in `deferred` in the `Department` controller is not declared inside the array i use this approach because minification.

Comment: I did not test this code specifically, but I do something very very similar. The resolve property exposes "deferred" for injection. Did you try this?

Comment: `deferred` is `undefined` note that i have to declare all the params like strings after the function

Comment: var Department = [
  '$scope',
  '$routeParams',
  **'deferred',**
  function (scope, routeParams, deferred) {...}
];

Comment: I see. I made a change to the code, I believe this should do the trick.

Comment: i try this one to, but don´t solve this issue maybe the  resolve object isn't ok :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48111/discussion-between-filipe-and-steve-farthing)